# Create constructor in base of Enum in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, enums, constructor

In my project I have the following enum:

```
public enum LicenseStateType
{
    Valid,
    Expiring,
    Expired
}
```

And the following class which represents a license state:

```
public class LicenseState
{
    public LicenseStateType State { get; protected set; }
    public int DaysLeft { get; protected set; }
}
```

In my scenario, when `LicenseStateType == LicenseStateType.Valid` or `LicenseStateType == LicenseStateType.Expired`I would create a contructor like `LicenseState(LicenseStateType Type)` but when `LicenseStateType == LicenseStateType.Expiring` I would send the number of days left calling a constructor like `LicenseState(LicenseStateType.Expiring, int daysleft)`.

How can I do it? Or there is better way to do this?

Comment: I would first question why you even need an enum in the first place. Especially since an expiring licence is still valid. You could remove it completely and use calculated properties in `LicenseState` like `public bool IsValid => DaysLeft > 0;` and `public bool IsExpiring => DaysLeft < 7;`

Comment: Enums are primarily a code readability feature. Under the hood, it is just a bunch of compile time constant being assigned to a integer variable. So how does this Enum improve code readability? And could a class Heirarchy based of 'abstract class LicenseStates' do that job better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no compile-time way to enforce different compiler signatures based on the *value* of parameters. So I see a few options:

- Make `DaysLeft` an *optional* compiler parameter and validate it at runtime
- Have a different type called `ExpiringLicenseState` that just takes a `DaysLeft` constructor parameter and passes `LicenseStateType.Expiring` to the base constructor. You could also move the `DaysLeft` property to that class since it's the only state where it is apparently relevant.

IF you know at compile time whether a license is expired, then the second would give you better compile-time safety. If you don't know at compile time, then runtime checks would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have one constructor where you pass the number of days left and let the internal logic decide its state? For example:

```
public LicenseState(int daysLeft)
{
    switch(daysLeft)
    {
        case <= 0:
            State = LicenseStateType.Expired;
            break;

        case <= 7:
            State = LicenseStateType.Expiring;
            break;

        default:
            State = LicenseStateType.Valid;
            break;
    };
}
```

Then you can drop the `DaysLeft` property, which, IMO, is pointless.

Comment: In this case, why even bother storing the `LicenseStateType` value? It's a pointless type.

Comment: I don't agree. It is in fact what is important, it's the state of the class. I would instead drop the DaysLeft property.

Comment: Except it's not the state, you could replace the `State` property with the `switch` statement you have here for example. It's also a badly designed enum, because an expiring licence is still valid meaning consumers need more complex routines to handle it.

Comment: It *is* a badly designed enum, IMO - what does it mean *Expiring*? And, yes, you could have a computed property that calculates the state on the fly, but this was based on the initial data of the problem that was presented.

Comment: At present when the license is expired the software doesn't even start. Now I would like to modify it so that it starts but shows the expired license message and when there are less than X days to warn with a warning that X days are missing for the expiration.